# How can I validate XML in the browser, or how should I do it otherwise?

Tags: xml, browser, xsd, schema

i'm not familiar with xsd, i copy the code from w3schools,

```
<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

the xsd

```
<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

i changed the item's maxOccurs to 1

```
<xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="1">
```

i run the xml in the browser (two items), it still print out the xml, so what is the usage of the xsd?

Comment: You need to use a validating parser. Browsers tend not have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i run the xml in the browser (two items), it still print out the xml, so what is the usage of the xsd?

An XSD, or XML Schema Definition, provides a definition for the XML. To utilize such a definition, you have to use a validating processor, such as Xerces (many others exist).

Its typical use case is when exchanging data between two parties. To be sure that the data conforms to their agreed format, they describe the format of the XML structure in some schema language:

- [DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition), [dtd](/questions/tagged/dtd), which is part of XML itself
- [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29), [xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd), arguably the most used standard
- [RelaxNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG), [relax-ng](/questions/tagged/relax-ng), a popular and more flexible alternative to XSD
- [Schematron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron), [schematron](/questions/tagged/schematron), a rule based validation language

Most commonly, you would find this when writing web services using the SOAP protocol, which defines its types typically in XSD. If you import a web service by its definition file (usually WSDL), it can be auto-converted into ready-to-use POJO or POCO classes (classes that represent the object model), which is a big aid in creating business logic.

For any scenario where there is a sending and a receiving end of data, it is a big plus if the receiver can validate whether the XML conforms to the datamodel defined in the schema, before it proceeds. Suppose you have a field `birth-date`, and the sender sends `"fourth of july 1977"`, a validator can raise an error, warning the user that something is wrong and allowing a system to [gracefully degrade](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110944/what-is-graceful-degradation).

Browsers have no business with schemas, at least not in the sense of reporting it back to the user, because they try to be liberal in what they accept, as so many people create HTML that is non-conformant, but should still display somehow.

Another obvious use is in standardization. For instance, the DocBook format [is defined in RelaxNG](http://docs.oasis-open.org/docbook/rng/5.0/) as is the [OpenDocument format](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/os/OpenDocument-v1.2-os-schema.rng). These are defined in XSD: [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#schema-for-xslt) (albeit non-normative), [XSD itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#schema), [WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#A4.1), [SMIL](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/REC-SMIL2-20050107/smil-SCHEMA.html), all [Office Open XML formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats), all parts of SOAP (here is [the envelope schema](http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope)). The  and so on, the list is long.